# Javascript: проверить, существует ли страница (видеофайл)

Tags: javascript, http, видео

Как узнать при помощи JS, существует ли файл по url (http://example.com/video.mp4) (большой видеофайл) или нет? Функция возвращает булевое значение.

Comment: а где хранится ваш видеофайл?

Comment: http://example.com/video.mp4

Comment: что хотите, что бы выводило при проверке?

Comment: Чтобы функция проверки возвращала булевое значение

Comment: ну давайте начнем с того, что у вас в json , какие параметры?

Comment: в кратце, вам нужен Ajax запрос на json файл на сервере, или просто файл у вас в корне проэкта, в котором будут параметры, на которые вы как раз и будете ссылаться, и если такого файла не существует, тогда вы пишите `data== false`

Comment: я не хочу вам писать весь код, включая в json покажите ваш пример, тогда я дам точный ответ

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич что именно вы ожидаете от примера?

Answer (score 0):

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();  
request.open('GET', 'http://example.com/video.mp4', true);
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (request.readyState === 4){
        if (request.status === 404) {  
            alert("Oh no, it does not exist!");
        } else {
            alert("Exists!");
        }
    }
};
request.send();
```

Comment: Тогда оно скачается целиком, это лишнее

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что будет затрата ресурсов на скачивание? Само видео у меня не сохранилось.

Comment: Во-первых, да, во-вторых, очень даже сохранилось в кэше браузера

Comment: Мм. Если просто существование страницы проверять, то не так критично будет?